# 'Cashier' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have this piece of code

```
#ifndef STATION_H
#define STATION_H

#include <vector>
#include "Dispenser.h"
#include "Cashier.h"

//class Cashier;

class Station
{
private:
    int price;
    int dispenser_count;
    int cashier_count;
    std::vector<Dispenser> dispensers;
    std::vector<Cashier> cashiers;

public:
    Station(int, int, int);
    int GetPrice() const { return price; }

    Dispenser *LookForUnoccupiedDispenser(int &id);
    Dispenser *GetDispenserByID(int id);

    Cashier *LookForUnoccupiedCashier();
};

#endif // STATION_H
```

When I have the `class Cashier` line commented, the compiler fails with a `'Cashier' was not declared in this scope` error even though `Cashier.h` was included. Uncommenting it makes it possible to compile but I'm concerned that it shouldn't be happening.

`Cashier.h`

```
#ifndef CASHIER_H
#define CASHIER_H

#include "Station.h"

class Station;

class Cashier
{
private:
    bool busy;
    Station *at_station;

public:
    Cashier(Station *employer);

    bool IsBusy() const { return busy; }
};


#endif // CASHIER_H
```

How is it possible? It's clearly declared in the header file and as far as I know, `#include` does nothing more than pasting the content of a file into another one.

Thank you for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your station.h includes cachier.h. This is an example of cyclic dependency. Given that you only have a pointer to `Station` in `Cachier` I'd suggest removing the dependency of `station.h` and forward declare it.

An `#include` is literally nothing more than verbatim copy and paste of that file into the current compilation unit. The guards protect you from the effect of an infinite include cycle, but due to the guards one of the `#include`s does nothing, i.e. does **NOT** suck in the declaration (nor definition) of the respective class. This results in the error you get. In station.h the compiler has never seen any mention of the `Cachier` type when it sees the `Station` type.

Comment: What would happen if I had a pointer to `Cashier` in `Station`? Or is that completely wrong design?

Comment: You'd still have to forward declare the type you are using as a pointer. Whether it is categorically bad design depends on your entire context. Having said that, in modern C++ you should try to avoid raw pointers unless you know why and when to ignore this very recommendation. Have a look at [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Note however, that this will not solve your cyclic inclusion problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and clarification. You helped me a lot!